# Laravel foreign key with img path

Tags: php, laravel, foreign-keys, laravel-5.1

I basically have this:

```
   foreach ($request->input('images', []) as $imagesData) {
       $images = new ScenesImages($imagesData);
       $images->product()->associate($product);
       $images->save();
   }
```

This saves correctly in my foreign key the name of the image/s but how do I safe the image path dynamicly here.

If I dd($product);

I get this:

```
>   #attributes: array:2 [▼
>     "name" => "test"
>     "product_id" => 7   ]
```

but no img(path)

Javascript which creates that html in a loop:

```
    for(var i = 1; i<slider.value; i++) {
        $('#sliderAppendSz').append(
        '<div class=\"form-group\">'
            +'<div class=\"fileinput fileinput-new\" data-provides=\"fileinput\">'
            +'<div class=\"input-group\">'
            +'<input name=\"images['+i+'][name]\" type=\"text\">'
                +'<span class=\"input-group-btn\">'
                    +'<span class=\"btn btn-primary btn-file\">'
                        +'<input name=\"images['+i+'][scenes_images]\" type=\"file\" multiple class=\"ImageInput\" accept=\"file_extension/*\">'
                    +'</span>'
                +'</span>'
            +'</div>'
        +'</div>');
    }
```

And my ScenesImages Model:

```
<?php

    namespace App;

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class ScenesImages extends Model
    {

        protected $table = 'scenes_images';

        protected $fillable = ['product_id', 'name', 'scenes_images'];

        public function product()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo('App\Product', 'product_id');
        }


    }
```

And here my Product Model:

```
<?php

    namespace App;

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class Product extends Model
    {

        public static $projects        = 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\MyProject\\Web';

        protected $table = 'products';

        protected $fillable = [
            'scenes_images'
        ];

        public static $rules = [
            'scenes_images'                     => 'max:500',                   
        ];

        public function scenesImages()
        {
            return $this->hasMany('App\ScenesImages');
        }

    }
```

Edit:

OK I think I got it I had to add this as since I only got input before I just added a foreach with a file, my question now is if it is somehow possible to sum the two foreach loops into one like $requesting->file and input.

```
  foreach ($request->file('images', []) as $imagesData) {
       $images = new ScenesImages($imagesData);
       $images->product()->associate($product);
       $images->save();
   }
```

Comment: Two questions: 1. Are `$request->input('images')` files? 2. It won't work unless `$imagesData` matches the attributes required by the `ScenesImages` model

Comment: Yes they are file or what do you mean excatly I create my html dynamic with javascript I can add a little so that you understand better.

Comment: Ok I extended my questiton hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Could be better if you show us more information about the model ScenesImages, otherwise maybe you can have something like this.

```
foreach ($request->input('images', []) as $imagesData) {
       $images = new ScenesImages($imagesData);
       $images->product()->associate($product);
       $images->path = $your_path

       $images->save();
   }
```

Of course you will need the variable `$your_path` with the path where is saved the images or if it's an url from Amazon S3, but as I said we need maybe more information about your Models structure.

Comment: I edited my answer:) what do you mean with Amazon S3?

Comment: That's an example where you can store your images, and get an url where the image is allocated

Comment: do you mean path or path()

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget upload the image, save it to the server

```
foreach ($request->input('images', []) as $imagesData)
{
    $images = new ScenesImages($imagesData);
    $images->product()->associate($product);

    $destinationPath = 'uploads'; // upload path
    $extension = $imagesData->getClientOriginalExtension(); // getting image extension
    $fileName = $imagesData->getClientOriginalName()'.'.$extension; // renameing image
    $imagesData->move($destinationPath, $fileName); // uploading file to given path

    $images->path = $destinationPath.'/'.$fileName;

    $images->save();
}
```

Comment: Thanks I get `a Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on a non-object` error message

Comment: hmm strange if I `dd($scenesImagesData);` I only get one name, whereas I entered 2, thus there no path is returning

Comment: Try to check if your files are reaching the server, on your form i cant see a file input, only text inputs
I don't really know how are you send the files to the server

Comment: I do have a fileinput line 9

Comment: do you mean path or path()

Answer (score 0):

Couple of issues I'm having with your code:

1. I'm a bit confused on what `$request->file('images')` returns. If it's an array of the [`UploadedFile`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/requests#files) object then I'm pretty sure you're doing it wrong. You're not even uploading the images to your server, once uploaded that's the file path you want to use when saving your `ScenesImages` model.
2. Your code here:

`$images = new ScenesImages($imagesData);`

is newing up a `ScenesImages` object and passing it a variable which would need to satisfy the model's required attributes to be created properly, its attributes being: `name`, `scenes_images` according to your question code. If you don't it's not going to work properly. You should be passing it an associative array with the keys matching the attributes the model has.

3. You should usually make your tables plural: `scene_images` and then your model singular: `SceneImage`

Consider doing your code like this:

```
$product = Product::first(); // assume you've defined this already
$uploadedImages = $request->file('images'); // get the images
$destinationPath = storage_path . '/uploads'; // somewhere to put your images

foreach ($uploadedImages as $uploadedImage) {
  // upload the image first!
  if ($uploadedImage->isValid()) {
      $extension = $uploadedImage->getClientOriginalExtension(); // file extension
      $uploadedImageName = uniqid(). '.' .$extension; // unique file name with extension
      $uploadedImage->move($destinationPath, $uploadedImageName); // move file to our uploads path
      // create ScenesImages record in DB
      $image = ScenesImages::create([
        'name' => $uploadedImageName, // assuming this is your file path?
        'scenes_images' => '' // assign something here, not sure what it's supposed to be?
      ]);
      // associate product
      $image->product()->associate($product);

  } else {
      // handle error here
  }
}
```